# How to define sum of multiple arbitrary functions?

Tags: python, function

Suppose I have a list of functions

```
f1(x,y),f2(x,y),....
```

How can I define the function below:

```
z(x,y)=f1(x,y)+f2(x,y)+...
```

I want to be able to specify x later. So if somebody puts the y=c value, I want the z function to become a function of x! In the simple case when you you have one function, f, and you want to make f(x,y) to be a function of x only by specifying y=c you can use:

```
z=lambda x:f(x,c)
```

but the thing is such a method won't work for more than one function!

Comment: Simply return that summation of all the three function call from `z(x, y)`?

Comment: If you mean arbitrarily many functions, you should be clearer. Sounds like you're just dealing with 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweaking the previous answers, we can throw in `functools.partial` to create the desired behavior.

We can do a partial function call (similar to the haskell construct) to produce new functions from incompletely applied functions. Check it out:

```
from functools import partial

funcs = [lambda x, y: x + y] * 10 # a list of ten placeholder functions.

def z(functions, x, y):
    return sum(f(x, y) for f in functions)

a = partial(z, funcs, 1)
# 'a' is basically the same as: lambda y: z(funcs, 1, y)
print a # <functools.partial object at 0x7fd0c90246d8>
print a(1) # 20
print a(2) # 30
print a(3) # 40
```

More here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Answer (score 5):

Can be useful for 10s of functions:

```
def z(x,y,functions):
    return sum(F(x,y) for F in functions)
```

So you can use it like:

```
z(x,y,(f,g,h))
```

Or if the number of functions comes from a list:

```
z(x,y,list_of_functions)
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what OP was actually asking.

Comment: If passing just one list, there's no reason to use * before.
Otherwise, your answer is more pythonic, deleting mine

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your functions in a list `functions`:

```
z = lambda x, y : sum((f(x, y) for f in functions))
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you have other arbitrary functions? What if you want to sum any old number of functions?

```
def funcSum(x, y, *funcs):
    return sum((func(x,y) for func in funcs))

funcSum(x, y, f, g, h)
```

Arbitrary numbers of arguments gets a little more complex...

Comment: Looks like Imre's answer is the lambda version of mine.

Comment: can I pass only y to this but not the x?! I want to be able to pass only one value and get the result as a function object of the other unspecified value

Comment: @Naji What? You pass both `y` and `x`. Your original question was not clear.